# Can we use CSV file in scenario hooks like in before feature to get data?

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

//since I have to get the data from CSV to backend before the application launched. Is there any alternative procedures?

Comment: Please provide more info

Comment: Before launching the application i would like to check whether it is in required services id or not in backend. If it is not in expected we have to change the service I'd using test data. Is it possible using scenario hooks like before feature or before scenario? I appreciate if you help me on this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Part of BDD automation best practices is to have the scenarios independent of any backend implementations or other scenarios. In your case, you shouldn't be checking if the service is available in the backend in order to run the scenario.

Or in other words, what would be the user experience if the service id is available in the backend? You may need to consider two scenarios; 1. How does your application behaves when the service id is available in the backend 2. How does it behave when it doesn't.

This is precisely the reason for using either Background of Hooks. Definitions are given below:

**Background:** Use Background when you want to execute business related pre-conditions to your scenarios like navigate to login page

**Hooks:** Use Before/After hooks when you have to do some technical setup before/after your scenarios like clearing databast etc...

IMHO, BDD automation should not have any business related logic. The moment you have any logic (e.g. if statements to check business related functions), you need to think if they should be turned into a scenario checking for that condition.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Sorry for confusion created there will be default service I'd for each respondent respectively in backend. While testing we need to test for different service IDs using test data. So it is possible to use test data from external CSV file in before feature hook. Please let me know